# Use of "column" css shorthand property leads to unwelcome result ( items are divided between columns0

Tags: html, css

I have applied CSS column shorthand perhaps beyond its regular application - while in all examples I have seen plain text inside it, in my case these were divs containing image and container with buttons. It worked in a more than satisfactory way as long as the divs were specifically styled (details later). After modifying styling due to some reasons, the layout breaks in an unwelcome way (while the image is on the bottom of one column, the buttons are on the top of the next one.

The specific styling mentioned above was absolute positioning of container with buttons on the bottom of the page. As long as I kept it, it was OK. When I remove it, it breaks.

I like the layout itself was basically as one can see (yes, it is my copy of Unplash site, nothing more) with infinite scroll working on it.
So, one can see it here:
[my-unsplash](https://kiszuriwalilibori.github.io/unsplash)
The way to reproduce:

1. Open the side
2. In input type "cat"
3. Press enter, and you will be redirected to a page that looks like this
   [image]

The structure of the page is like this:

```
<>
            <Subject />
            <ImagesContentWrapper>
                <Loading ref={loadingRef}>Loading images</Loading>
                <div className="fotos__grid">
                    <ImagesContainer ref={refContainer}>
                        {images.map(image => (
                            <Image key={uuid()} {...image} loadHandler={loadHandler} />
                        ))}
                        <ViewportBottomMarker onEnterViewport={getMoreImages} />
                    </ImagesContainer>
                </div>
            </ImagesContentWrapper>
        </>
```

"Columns" are on div with "fotos__grid" class. ImagesContainer - its direct and only child - is not guilty - I have tried with and without it.

Consciously, I do not copy more code here. That is complex, to be short. But, please do not undervote for that. If you would like to help and think some code is needed, just write.

What have I checked so far is basically that absolute position is the only game changer in this case. I know that MUI perhaps offers solution, but I would rather keep what I already have. Could someone tell me how to change the layout keeping features mentioned above?

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example. You can simplify your code for this purpose by providing the generated HTML and CSS rather than the source code. We just need enough to see the problem in action and demonstrate the solution.

Comment: @Alohci The problem was that I had no idea on why that happens. Could not then decide wht to remove to on one hand present clean picture, on other hand ot to lose any of the important apects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `break-inside` to control breaks in multi-column layout. To prevent breaks inside boxes, use:

```css
figure {
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

More about breaks: [Handling content breaks in multi-column layout (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_multicol_layout/Handling_content_breaks_in_multicol_layout)

Comment: Thank you! It solves the problem like charm. The property never heard before - it is time to refresh CSS perhaps. Thanks again :)